# ActiveRecord includes not doing what I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Program
  attr_accessible :open, ...
  has_many :rounds
  has_many :open_rounds, :class_name => 'Round', :conditions => ['open = ?', true]
end

class Round
  belongs_to :program
  attr_accessible :open, :status, :begin ...
end

[64] pry(main)> a = Program.includes(:rounds)
  Program Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs"
  Round Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rounds".* FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."program_id" IN (4, 6)
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| id | name        | moderato... | descrip... | open  | locked | suppress... | created_at | updated_at  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 4  | Advanced... |             | Summer ... | false | true   | false       | 2013-04... | 2013-04-... |
| 6  | Introduc... |             | Summer ... | false | true   | false       | 2013-04... | 2013-04-... |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set
[65] pry(main)>
```

The SQL looks like what I would expect, but I would have expected to see the other columns of Round in the result of the query.

And example two is the same but more confusing. Notice that Program 4 has no open rounds:

```
[67] pry(main)> Program.find(6).rounds
  Program Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Round Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rounds".* FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."program_id" = 6
+----+------------+--------+-------+-----+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| id | program_id | number | start | fin | status | open  | open_date | created_at     | updated_at     |
+----+------------+--------+-------+-----+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| 10 | 6          | 0      | 0     | 10  |        | false |           | 2013-04-13 ... | 2013-04-13 ... |
| 11 | 6          | 1      | 11    | 21  |        | false |           | 2013-04-13 ... | 2013-04-13 ... |
| 12 | 6          | 2      | 22    | 32  |        | false |           | 2013-04-13 ... | 2013-04-13 ... |
| 13 | 6          | 3      | 33    | 43  |        | false |           | 2013-04-13 ... | 2013-04-13 ... |
+----+------------+--------+-------+-----+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
4 rows in set
```

Yet when I do:

```
[68] pry(main)> a = Program.includes(:open_rounds)
  Program Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs"
  Round Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rounds".* FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."program_id" IN (4, 6) AND (open = 'f')
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| id | name        | moderato... | descrip... | open  | locked | suppress... | created_at | updated_at  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 4  | Advanced... |             | Summer ... | false | true   | false       | 2013-04... | 2013-04-... |
| 6  | Introduc... |             | Summer ... | false | true   | false       | 2013-04... | 2013-04-... |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

Not only don't I see the Round attributes, but I see Program 6 which I didn't expect. Again the SQL looks ok except perhaps the "AND (open ='f'). Because notice that there's a column called open in both Program and Round.

Sorry for all the dumps but I wanted to lay out the evidence clearly. Thoughts?

Comment: Is the colon on the wrong side on line 3 in your code as well? Maybe it's not understanding that association, just the scoped one below that.

Comment: that was just a typo. Corrected.